# How to set labels text align to top UITableViewCell in iOS

Tags: ios, swift3

I have tableViewCell which contain two labels with title and subtitle .Both have numberOfLine 0 with sizeToFit in cell class.But if text of one them is less then label text with less one, comes at center as

[image: mismatched]

Cell height is base on Label text size and if both Label text have same number of line then it appear good . So i want text of both label align to top.Cell height should be base of text of Label with more number of line.

Comment: How are you creating these cells, are they initialised from xibs using auto layout?

Comment: yes, they initialised from xibs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved in auto layout by setting the bottom labels constraint to >= rather than just = to the bottom of the cell in the xib. That way it should automatically  fill the least amount of space so that text vertical alignment is no longer an issue.

Comment: Oh! Nice ,Thank you very much